# How to display matplotlib histogram data as table?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bins

So I am just trying to learn Python and have built a histogram that looks like such:

[image]

I've been going crazy trying to figure out how I could display this same data in a table format ie:

```
  0-5  = 50,500
  5-10 = 24,000
 10-50 = 18,500
```

and so on...

There is only one field in df, and it contains the number of residents in towns/cities.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

From the duplicate question answer... I GET AN ERROR

```
bins = [0,5,10,50,150,500,2500,5000,8000]
groups = df.groupby(['Total_Residents', pd.cut(df.Total_Residents, bins)])
groups.size().unstack()
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 bins = [0,5,10,50,150,500,2500,5000,8000]
----> 2 groups = df.groupby(['Total_Residents', pd.cut(df.Total_Residents, bins)])
      3 groups.size().unstack()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **getattr**(self, name)
   4370             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   4371                 return self[name]
-> 4372             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
   4373 
   4374     def **setattr**(self, name, value):

```
 AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Total_Residents'
```

EDIT: For Sample data, you can use the bin values +1

df = pd.Series([1,6,11,51,151,501,2501,5001,8001], name = 'Total_Residents')

but fwiw, my data wasn't causing the issue.  It was that I was using a function of pandas meant for a dataframe on a series of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby with bin counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317149/pandas-groupby-with-bin-counts)

Comment: I tried that and still didn't work.

Comment: include sample data, otherwise we can't replicate your error

Comment: it says df is a series, change your code to `df =dataset[['Total_Residents']]`

Comment: the sample data is just integers.  any random integers would work.

Comment: yes, so give us the code to run your random integers, we're not going to do the extra work for you

Comment: Just use the bin values +1 for the integers.  I didn't think that would have been any more work than for me copy and paste them.  My apologies, I should have just done that in the last edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was not able to actually convert the 'series' to a dataframe but pandas has the ability to work with a series:

```
  bins = [0,5,10,50,150,500,2500,5000,8000]
  df.value_counts(bins=bins)
```

I needed to use the value_counts function.

I was able to use the suggestion duplicate answer only if I had another column to group the data by.

Comment: It's great that this works for you, but it isn't supported by the documentation. `bins` is only supposed to be an integer according to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html but looking at the source the parameter is passed to `cut` which does actually accept a sequence of scalars https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html So I think your approach is safe despite the documentation conflict.

Comment: @beldaz: or it might be a case of a legit, but underdocumented, feature in pandas? (I find such things occasionally). Have you considered raising a [pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/)?