# How to take the sum of every values when its sum is 1000 and put in a new dataframe

Tags: pandas

1. I have a Dataframe with 15992 indexes.
2. I would like to loop over the dataset and take the sum of cells that falls within 999 to 1000.
3. And if the sum falls into this range, group them accordingly.
4. Take its Range, sum, count of range, mean, max, min to a new dataframe.

I'm really new at using Pandas, I don't know if it's possible. Please kindly have a look at the images below.

Thank you

| Frame Offset | FrameTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13.423 |
| 2 | 11.764 |
| 3 | 12.243 |
| 5 | 12.508 |
| ... | ... |
| 1995 | 49.559 |
| 1996 | 58.300 |
| 1997 | 56.943 |
| 1998 | 37.577 |
| 1999 | 57.111 |

Name: FrameTime, Length: 15992, dtype: float64

Here's are the process I would like to automat;
[image]

Here's what it should look like;
[image]

Comment: How can the sum of FrameTime be 1000 when the lowest value seems to be 13.423?

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your post and the data you have processed manually in Excel so that we try to see what you mean. Please also see [how to produce a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for you questions at StackOverflow.

Comment: i think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317149/pandas-groupby-with-bin-counts) will be useful here